# With what exponent rules does $-(2^{-55} + .4\times2^{-56})+(2^{-54})$ become $.1\times2^{-52}$?

Tags: numerical-methods, exponentiation, floating-point

I have a math class focusing on numerical analysis so I'm working with very small numbers. My professor has set $0.4 − 2^{−55} − 0.4×2^{−56} + 2^{−54} = 0.4 + 0.1×2^{-52}$ but shown no steps in between.

Clearly the initial $0.4$ can be taken out and we can set the remainder of both sides equal to one another, but that doesn't really help me. This is supposed to be a small step to look over so she has not explained it, but I can't seem to figure on my own why this is true. Specifically we're working on floating point representations of decimal numbers for double precision. Is $-2^{−55} − 0.4×2^{−56} + 2^{-54} = 0.1×2^{-52}$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2^{-54}-2^{-55}-0.4\times2^{-56}$$

$$=4\times2^{-56}-2\times2^{-56}-0.4\times2^{-56}$$

$$=1.6\times2^{-56}$$

$$=0.1\times2^{-52}$$